# Custom Material Icon

Tags: flutter, android-icons, google-material-icons, custom-icons

How can I make a custom Material Icon and use it in my flutter project.

I was trying to get "comment" icon that is used in Instagram, but I couldn't get the exact one.

Is there any tool where I can make icons that can be used in my project.

Comment: Please try to refer [icon class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) ,for (https://www.fluttericon.com/)[flutter icon], (https://fonts.google.com/icons)[Google icons]

Comment: checkout fontawesome implementation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter_svg to custom your svg icon https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Answer (score 0):

Here's the kind of icon your are looking for, for free: [Icon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/bubble-chat_3031126?term=comment&page=1&position=6&origin=search&related_id=3031126). You can just download it's png and use it with `Image.asset` widget.